# iMac as display for Windows PC

Tags: imac

I'd like to use a mid 2011 iMac screen as target video of my Dell PC (using dock station display link). I want to work on my Windows PC, but using 27" LCD monitor of my iMac.

How do I do it? Is it possible using software (display link?) or using a common USB cable?

Comment: @NimeshNeema, et al: Not sure this is an exact duplicate as Dells offer display port video interfces, whereas many garden-variety PCs do not.

Comment: Have you looked at [this approach?](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-apple-monitor-pc-57232.html)

Comment: What ports does your PC have? Also, which dock station are you using? Please edit the question and specify the details.